# Создать данные для StreamReader C#

Tags: c#, .net

Необходимо в процедуре записать данные куда-либо, чтобы в итоге можно было прочитать эти данные через `StreamReader`.

Пробовал создать `MemoryStream`, с помощью `StreamWriter` записать данные, и создать `StreamReader`.

```
Stream _stream =new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter _sw = new StreamWriter(_stream);
_sw.Write("1232");
StreamReader _sr = new StreamReader(_stream);
char[] _c = new char[3];
_sr.Read(_c, 0, 3);
// ...
```

Возможно вообще такое сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232443/writing-to-then-reading-from-a-memorystream

Answer (score 2):

Нужно после записи в MemoryStream сбросить данные и позицию с помощью такого
кода.

```
_sw.Flush();
_stream.Position = 0;
```

Эти строчки надо вставить после записи, но до чтения.